# BQ Load Jobs all stuck in pending

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been developing a batch upload system for BigQuery.  It was working great on my development system.

I moved it all over to production, and it seems to be working fine, except that all my BQ jobs are stuck in the PENDING state.

In all my testing over the last several days, all jobs started executing within seconds and completed within about 30 seconds.

I have checked the job status via the API test link at:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get

Is there something I might have done that caused this?  Or is there something else I can do to track down the problem?

An example jobID I am using is: 8-eb1c535d-5546-4f94-af90-ed04c1c3abcb

Thanks!

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Batch jobs have been pending for about an hour now

Comment: They seem to have shifted to "running" but none have completed.

Comment: They've all completed and jobs seem to be running normally.  I'm happy in that it apparently wasn't anything I did, but if anyone from BQ sees this, I'd still like to know what the issue was and, more importantly, if I can get any inside into what's going on with the BQ system that might affect my activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was some Google-related thing.